# SQL saves PRIMARY KEY of deleted line

Tags: mysql, sql

I had an AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY "student_id", inserted a line in the table. It got student_id equals **1**. Then `I deleted this line` and `inserted new line`. The new line got student_id of **2**, instead of **1**. Why? How to change it?

I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE students DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (student_id);
```

However it had no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how autoincrementing keys work. Each autoincrement operation is guaranteed to give back a new unique value. There's no logic built into the database server to try to figure out whether some values are available for reuse because their rows were DELETEd.

Why not? Often these key values are stored in other tables (implementing the Relational part of Relational Database Management System).  If they were reused the relationships would become corrupted.

You can reset the next auto increment value with

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
```

But, if you do this you may mess things up pretty badly. Don't do this until you gain experience with JOIN operations on autoincrementing values.

Answer (score 2):

You should never modify the value of an auto increment key. They are there to uniquely identify a record, and primary keys can have gaps in them without consequences.

From MySql [documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html):

> To reset the current auto-increment value:
>
> ```
> `ALTER TABLE t1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 13`;
> ```
>
> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the
> value that is currently in use.

Answer (score 2):

That's how `auto_increment works`, it increases after each `INSERT`. It never fills the holes left after you delete some record.

If you really want to reuse the `student_id = 1` after you delete, you can `INSERT` using `INSERT INTO students (student_id) VALUES (1)`.

[MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how AUTO_INCREMENT works in MySQL. It never assigns the same id value twice. You can try to change the current behaviour by removing AUTO_INCREMENT from your PK column and assigning student_id values by hand if you really need to. I wouldn't recommend this approach though and would stick with auto incremented values for consistency reasons.